# How to optimize the python code (running time should be less than 10s)?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, optimization

I have to optimize the code, as the running time of the code goes above `10s`.  The code works absolutely fine (less than `10s`) for small inputs if the input length increases then the output goes above `10s`.

```
import re, time
#from collections import OrderedDict
final_dict = {}
k_m_n = input()
k_m_n = list(map(lambda x: int(x), re.findall(r'([0-9]+)', k_m_n)))
AI = []
start = time.time()
for i in range(k_m_n[2]):
    AI.append(int(input()))
AI_sort, l = sorted(AI), len(AI)


i = 0
while i < l:
    final_dict[AI_sort[i]] = cnt = AI_sort.count(AI_sort[i])
    i += cnt
print(final_dict)
i = 0
for k in sorted(final_dict, key=final_dict.get, reverse=True):
    if i < k_m_n[0]:
        print(k)
        i += 1

print(time.time()-start)
```

if the input is

`k_m_n  = 3 3 8`
and `AI.append(int(input())) = 2 2 1 1 1 5 5 5`. It works fine.

if the input is `k_m_n = 999 999 256000` and `AI.append(int(input()))= 1..999..1...999`(then the time goes above `10s`). Please help.

```
K = 3: Number of output I want to see
m = 3: Number of different types of numbers
n = 8: List of numbers

Suppose 
AI.append(int(input())) = 2 2 1 1 1 5 5 5
Here there are 3 types of number provided (2,1,5) # m
Total numbers in the list are = 8 # n
Outputs required in lexical order here is 1 5 2 #k.. although 1 and 5 are repeated 3 times but I need to print 1 then 5 then 2
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: clearly 3, but what is this computing?

Comment: I am using Python3

Comment: @MK: See the update

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers) your code to locate any bottlenecks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary culprit is the counting code, which unnecessarily scales with `O(m*n)`, if `n` is the number of inputs and `m` is the number of unique inputs. That is, this part:

```
i = 0
while i < l:
    final_dict[AI_sort[i]] = cnt = AI_sort.count(AI_sort[i])
    i += cnt
```

This implementation walks through the list entirely to count the elements for each unique element in the list, resulting in `m*n` iterations in total (resulting in ~256 million iterations for your larger example).

Switching it to this implementation solves that problem and improves the runtime quite a lot (I'm not getting your 10+ seconds to begin with, though, but perhaps that's a difference in hardware performance):

```
final_dict = {}
for a in AI_sort:
    final_dict[a] = final_dict.get(a, 0) + 1
```

That being said, though, there are quite some other unnecessary things that the program does as well. It could be written with far less code this way:

```
import collections

k, m, n = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
occurrences = collections.Counter(int(input()) for i in range(n))
for num, seen in occurrences.most_common(k):
    print(seen)
```

Comment: I did not understand which part of my code need to be replaced with your code?